# What does this obfuscated javascript snippet mean/do?

Tags: javascript

I cannot understand what this little snippet: `var num = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` does.

Context:

```
function retnum(str) {
    var num = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    var liczba = parseInt(num);
    return liczba;
}
```

Comment: That's just a basic way to convert any string to a number

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: this isn't even obfuscated, you should read about regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This JavaScript snippet will rip out anything that is not (the `^` part of the regular expression means "not") a number in `str` and then return an integer cast from the result as `liczba`. See my comments:

```
// This function will return a number from a string that may contain other characters.
// Example: "1.23" -> 123
// Example: "a123" -> 123
// Example: "hg47g*y#" -> 47

function retnum(str) {
    // First let's replace everything in str that is not a number with "" (nothing)
    var num = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    // Let's use JavaScript's built in parseInt() to parse an Integer from the remaining string (called "num")
    var liczba = parseInt(num);
    // Let's now return that Integer:
    return liczba;
}
```

By the way, "liczba" means number in Polish :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation and guide through the steps in the code!

Comment: No problem Adam! Could you please mark my answer correct if you though it answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

This function takes a string, strips all non-number characters from it, turns the string into an integer, and returns the integer. The line you're asking about specifically is the part that strips out all non-number characters from the initial string, using the [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obfuscated, it's using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

The expression matches all things which are not numbers then removes them. `0-9` means "any digit" and the `^` means "not". The `g` flag means to check the entire string instead of just the first match. Finally, the result is converted to a number.

Example:

```js
var input = 'abc123def456';
var str = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
var num = parseInt(str);
document.querySelector('pre').innerText = num;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It literally just replaces anything which is not a number with a blank ('').